# How to get difference of a time in seconds in PHP?

Tags: php, time

I have a database column with datatype "time" which stores 11:30:45. I have fetched this time in a variable say

```
$databasetime = 11:30:45
```

I want to declare a variable say `$currenttime` which will contain time just now. Like its 11:33:30 right now and another variable which will contain their difference in seconds like

```
$timediff = $currenttime - $databasetime;
echo $timediff;
```

I am trying `$currenttime = time();` but I am not getting the result which I desire. I want `$timediff = 165` but when I echo time(), I am getting a very big value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$databasetime = strtotime('11:30:45');
$curtime      = time();
echo $curtime - $databasetime;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$currentTime = time();
$futureDateTime = new DateTime('11:30:45'); // might want to specify a date and timezone, system TZ by default
$futureTime = $futureDateTime->format('U'); // get unix timestamp
$timeDiff = $futureTime-$currentTime;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way:

```
$databasetime = '11:30:45';
$time1 = strtotime($databasetime);
$time2 = strtotime('now');
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
echo 'your difference: '.date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

Comment: Not working. Current time on my system is 21:25. When I am setting $databasetime = '21:24:00', I am getting difference 18:32:35. I don't know how it is calculated?

Comment: what do you see if you will echo $time1 and $time2?

Answer (score 1):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('10:35:56 2013-11-17');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10:35:50 2013-11-17');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds <br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

```
$databasetime = '11:30:45';
$timedif = abs(strtotime('now') - strtotime($databasetime));
echo $timedif; //echos the difference in seconds.
```

`abs` is used just to prevent neg numbers, which you may or may not want to do.

Comment: @hocat - I am not getting -ve values now but difference is too big. I just tried not and getting time difference of 19755 seconds. But actual difference is of around 2-3 minutes.

Comment: @hocat - Is PHP picking now() from machine time or from somewhere else because I am giving $databasetime 2-3 minutes lower than now.

Comment: @nkp unfortunately The problem would usually be timezone setting that could put if off by at an hour or more. What version of php are you running? php 5.3.2-1 has [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/907816) which does something similar. If you need a bad idea for temporary work around, so you can keep developing, you could do something like `strtotime('now -5hours')`.

Comment: no, I need permanent solution for this. I am using echo abs(strtotime('now') - strtotime('21:16:00'))."  "; Current time on my machine is 21:17 and I am getting difference as 19615 instead of around 60.

Comment: @nkp has has to be a timezone issue. you can run `echo date_default_timezone_get()' to see what your timezone is set to.

Comment: @nkp you could run script like the following that will tell you the differece for all timezones. you could use this info then set the timezone in your php.ini file. `$tzl = timezone_identifiers_list();
foreach($tzl as $tz){
    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
    echo $tz.PHP_EOL;
    echo abs(strtotime('now') - strtotime($databasetime)).PHP_EOL;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You use the DateTime 'OO' methods to return 'unix timestamp' integers directly

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime('now');
$date = new DateTime('11:30:45');
echo $now->getTimestamp() - $date->getTimestamp();
?>
```

Comment: its not working. giving -ve value in thousands, -19541 which is wrong.

Comment: It is probably the timezone on the server vs. what you are storing in the database. Try adding date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); or whatever valid timezone you are using.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved now. Actually all answers are right but the problem was due to the default time zone. I wanted Asia/Kolkata time zone but default European timezone apache was picking. That's why I was not getting my desired results.

So, I am finally using below code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$databasetime = strtotime('11:30:45');
$curtime      = time();
echo $curtime - $databasetime;
```