# PHP time() function is not giving desired results

Tags: php, time

I want to get the difference of time in seconds. I am using following code to get the difference but its giving me some weird outputs.

```
$databasetime = strtotime('21:30:45');
$curtime      = time();
echo $curtime - $databasetime;
```

For example, at the time of writing this question, its 21:31 on my laptop, So if run this script, desired result should be around around 60, but I am getting values like -19615.

I don't know how is it getting calculated? I had asked similar question on stackoverflow in afternoon, but my problem is not yet resolved.

[How to get difference of a time in seconds in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028237/how-to-get-difference-of-a-time-in-seconds-in-php)

Please help me in fixing my problem as this small piece of code took away my whole day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $databasetime = strtotime('21:30:45'); 
  $curtime = time(); 

  $timeDiff= $curtime - $databasetime;

  echo round(abs($timeDiff) / 60,2). " minute";
```

to get IST time,

```
       echo "Original Time: ". date("h:i:s")."\n"
       date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        echo "Indian Standart time Time: ". date("h:i:s")."\n";
```

Comment: According to the PHP manual, "strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp". time() is "time — Return current Unix timestamp". So you parse a Unix timestamp from a Unix timestamp? :)

Comment: @Chinnu - Its not working dude. I have tried it hundreds of time today. I got result 319.43 minute by running your script. Right now its 21:42 on my system.

Comment: It used the apache default timezone, it is not used your system time zone;  echo date('d M Y H:I:s'); check this one

Comment: @ChinnuR - How should I change apache time zone?

Comment: i have update code, check system time and server time are same now

Comment: @ChinnuR - Chinnu and Fred - You people solved my problem by telling me the settings of timezone before using time difference. My problem is resolved now. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: NP, Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

for time difference use diff

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('10:35:56 2013-11-15');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10:35:50 2013-11-15');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds <br/>";
```

Another way

```
$hour_one = "21:30:45";
$h =  strtotime($hour_one);
$h2 = time(); //current time

$minute = date("i", $h);
$second = date("s", $h);
$hour = date("H", $h);

$convert = strtotime("-$minute minutes", $h2);
$convert = strtotime("-$second seconds", $convert);
$convert = strtotime("-$hour hours", $convert);
$new_time = date('H:i:s', $convert);
echo $new_time;
```